# how to convert byte valueto hex and then to decimal which is from bluetooth spp device as hex value in android

Tags: android, hex, decimal

how to convert 35 bytes of hex values to decimal coming from bluetooth serial port communnication.. i am using bluetooth chat application, the device sending data in hex format of 35 bytes....
my code giving output like: 10 oa ff 00 3c................11
my code..
Bluetoothservice.java

```
public void run() {

            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[35];
            int bytes;            
            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); 
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

MainActivity.java

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj; 

String readMessage = BytesTrans.bytes2HexString(readBuf,msg.arg1);

mArrayAdapter.addAll(mConnectedDeviceName+":  "+ readMessage );

public static class BytesTrans {

        public static String bytes2HexString(byte[] b, int count) {
            String ret = "";
            //String str ="";
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(b[i] & 0xFF); 
                if (hex.length() ==1) {
                   hex = '0' + hex;               
                    }
                ret += hex.toUpperCase() + " ";                              
            }
            return ret;
        }`
```

Comment: So you are able to get the `bytes` to cast into hex and the hex to display in a string so far, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public static String bytes2String(byte[] b, int count) {
        String ret = "";
        //String str ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String myInt = Integer.toString((int)(b[i] & 0xFF)); 

            ret.append(myInt + " ");                             
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I think this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: now it displaying as 16 00 255 127....17,but i want to display 13th byte in a textview...how ?

Comment: @user2296132 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 13th byte? It should loop through and display all available bytes. Also, did you need it separated by more than just the space? Or were you able to get that part taken care of with the space?

Comment: the device sending 28 bytes of data.so i want to display that particular byte value in text view.packet format                  Si No. Parameter            Number of Bytes
1 Start of Packet Identifier 1
2 Emergency Button         1
3 Colour Code                 1
4 Heart Rate                 1
5 Respiration rate 1
6 Blood Pressure 4
7 Oxygen Saturation 1
8 Perfusion Index 2
9 Temperature 2
10 Reserve Bytes 12
11 Checksum 1
12 End of Packet Identifier 1
Total number of bytes 28